# No recipients defined error even though console.log shows my entered mail address

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I have followed a tutorial from dev https://dev.to/jlong4223/how-to-implement-email-functionality-with-node-js-react-js-nodemailer-and-oauth2-2h7m

My problem is that even though I enter user email, and console.log shows the correct email in both server code and email input code.
I still get error: No recipients defined.
I have changed my "to" parameter in mailOptions to "mymail@gmail.com" and this works great.

Here is my code;

server code

```
transporter.verify((err, success) => {
  err
    ? console.log(err)
    : console.log(`=== Server is ready to take messages: ${success} ===`);
 });
 
 
 app.post("/send", function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.body.email); //shows entered mail
  let mailOptions = {
    from: "some@mail.com",
    to: '${req.body.email}',
    subject: "Message from: ",
    text: "Reset password",
  };
 
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.json({
        status: "fail",
      });
    } else {
      console.log("== Message Sent ==");
      res.json({
        status: "success",
      });
    }
  });

 });
```

code for submitting email

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

async function handleReset(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(email);
   const response = await fetch("http://localhost:2525/send", {
     mode: "cors",
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
       "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
     body: JSON.stringify({ email }),
   })
   .then((res) => res.json())
   .then(async (res) => {
     const resData = await res;
     if (resData.status === "success") {
       alert("Message Sent");
      
      } else if (resData.status === "fail") {
       alert("Message failed to send");
       
     }
   });
}
```

```
Error: No recipients defined
    at SMTPConnection._formatError
    at SMTPConnection._setEnvelope 
    at SMTPConnection.send 
    at sendMessage 
    SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete 
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> 
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse 
    at SMTPConnection._onData 
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  command: 'API'
```

Really appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0):

You should use backticks with the `to` parameter in the `app.post("/send")` callback function:

```
to: `${req.body.email}`
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! it finally worked